# Merging function declarations

Tags: doxygen

I have following requirement in my project,

**qualifier1** foo(int a, int b, int c); -- In header file header_1.h

**qualifier2** foo(int a, int b, int c); -- In header file header_2.h

Where,  **qualifier1** is not equal to **qualifier2**.

Can I document the function declaration as shown below using Doxygen,

**qualifier1** **qualifier2** foo(int a, int b, int c);

Thanks.

Comment: Is that even legal to do in C? Also, C or C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INPUT_FILTER option with sed utility solved my problem as shown,

INPUT_FILTER = "sed -e 's/_qualifier1_ foo/_qualifier1_ _qualifier2_ foo/"

** Note the \ (escape) character use to avoid unknown character errors.

Comment: Could you give more information in that answer? It might be useful to others and could earn you some cred.